# Passing longitude and latitude to a java class

Tags: java, android

I need to find the least distant pharmacy and add its id to a table in the database.

```
public class gpslocation implements LocationListener {
private final Context mContext;
protected LocationManager locationManager;

boolean checkGPS = false;


boolean checkNetwork = false;

boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location loc;
double latitude;
double longitude;
String city;
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;


private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;

public gpslocation(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    getLocation();
}


public Location getLocation() {

    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        checkGPS = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        checkNetwork = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!checkGPS && !checkNetwork) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "No Service Provider Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (checkNetwork) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Network", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                try {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    }

                    if (loc != null) {
                        latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                        longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                    }
                } catch (SecurityException e) {

                }
            }
        }

        // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
        if (checkGPS) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (loc == null) {
                try {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (loc != null) {
                            latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                            longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    Log.d("Exce", e + "");
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return loc;
}


public double getLongitude() {
    if (loc != null) {
        longitude = loc.getLongitude();
    }
    return longitude;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    if (loc != null) {
        latitude = loc.getLatitude();
        // loc.
    }
    return latitude;
}

public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}


public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);


    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Not Enabled");

    alertDialog.setMessage("Do you wants to turn On GPS");


    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });


    alertDialog.show();
}

public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {

        // locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5


        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
        city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
        String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
        String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
        // Only if available else return NULL

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Longitude:" + Double.toString(longitude) + "\nLatitude:" + Double.toString(latitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
 //    Boolean checkgps = true;
//    String gps = String.valueOf(checkgps);
}
```

this is my code to find latitude and longitude in Android Studio.

```
package DatabasePackage;

 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONObject;



public class locationcalculation {
double distance;
boolean b;
int i;
ConnectionClass con=new ConnectionClass();

public String getlocation(String lat1,String lon1){
    String a="";
    String se="Select * from tbl_pharmacy ";
    ResultSet rs=con.selectCommand(se);
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject job;
    try{
        while(rs.next()){
            String lattitude=rs.getString("lattitude");
            String longitude=rs.getString("longitude");
           double dis=Calculation(lat1, lattitude, lon1, longitude);
           distance=dis;
           if(dis<=10){
               job=new JSONObject();
               job.put("distance", distance);
               job.put("id", rs.getString("phar_id"));
               ja.put(job);
              break; 
           }
           else if(dis<5){

               break;
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception ex){

    }


  return ja.toString();  
}
public double Calculation(String latt1,String latt2,String longg1,String longg2){
   String j="";
      final int R = 6371; // Radius of the earth
      double lat1=Integer.parseInt(latt1);
      double lat2=Integer.parseInt(latt2);
      double lon1=Integer.parseInt(longg1);
      double lon2=Integer.parseInt(longg2);

double theta = lon1 - lon2;
    double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1))
            * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2))
            + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1))
            * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2))
            * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
    dist = Math.acos(dist);
    dist = rad2deg(dist);
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;


           return (dist);
}

private double deg2rad(double deg) {
    return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
}

private double rad2deg(double rad) {
    return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
}
  }
```

This is my java class (written in NetBeans) to find the distance between two pairs of latitude and longitude. one pair is to be obtained from the android device and other pair from the heidisql database.

```
   String Dis=distance.getlocation(latt, lon);

   String str1="insert into 
  tbl_prescription(prescription,user_id)values('"+value[0]+"','1')";
  //  String str1="insert into 
    tbl_prescription(prescription)values('"+value[0]+"')";
  // System.out.println(str1

  //out.println(str1);

boolean status=con.executeCommand(str1);
```

this is where i have to call the function getLocation()(also written in NetBeans but in a different jsp page) that is defined in the java class. But I do not know how to get the value from the android device to this function call. Can someone solve this for me?

Comment: As an aside, don't catch `Exception`, especially if you don't do anything about it when you catch it.

Comment: _"But I do not know how to get the value from the android device to this function call."_ In your NetBeans you'll code a REST API or similar solutions by which the Android device can send (HTTP POST) the required information. _"Can someone solve this for me?"_  Well, you'll need to do most of the work yourself, but StackOverflow can help with smaller, more specific programming problems.